# How to specify encoding in MVC3 Html.Beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have MVC3 view page like below,

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = "https://www.paymentdummysite.com/abcd" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
        <div class="homePageSubSecContnt">
            <p>You will be re directed to your banking site.</p>
            @Html.Hidden("version",Model.cvsVersion)
            @Html.Hidden("bill_method", Model.cvsBillMethod)
            @Html.Hidden("shop", Model.ShopCode)
            @Html.Hidden("shopmsg", Model.shopmsg)
            @Html.Hidden("password", Model.password) 
            <input type="submit"  id="Next" name="Next"  value="Next" class="buttonStyle_2"   />
        </div>
```

the above code re-directs me to the banking site. Here i have provided absolute url and not calling any controller.I am using 2 html form in this view page, so that i can get model details from the 1st html form GET method of controller.

Now i have to encode the form data(hidden input) and re direct to external url. My encoding format is Shift-JIS which is japanese encoding format. I am not sure, how to do encoding in view page. Can anyone throw light on this?

In C# code i can do encoding as below,

```
byte[] postDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift-JIS").GetBytes(postData);
```

how to do the same encoding in view page?

```
<meta charset="Shift-JIS">  Will this work?
```

I think i have to use charset="Shift-JIS", but how to use it in mvc forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time i have found answer myself:

Since my code has japanese text and i want encoding format as Shift_jis , even if i specify charset or encoidng format the code is not working perfectly.

The solution is:
Go to file menu in visual studio,

> File->advanced save options->Unicode-codepage 1200(3rd option)->Click
>   Ok.

This will solve your problem.